# Output events not being generated by oozie coordinator

Tags: hadoop, oozie

My coordinator app is successfully reading from the input events and executing the workflow at the nominal time, however output events are not being generated at all.

I tried setting the output event with without a done flag, but it did not work. What have I done wrong?

Below is my coordinator.xml file.

```
 <coordinator-app name="wf_scheduler" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
    start="2016-12-14T00:00Z" end="2016-12-19T00:00Z" timezone="IST"
    xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2">
    <controls>
        <timeout>30</timeout>
        <concurrency>3</concurrency>
        <execution>FIFO</execution>
        <throttle>3</throttle>
    </controls>
    <datasets>
        <dataset name="inp_logs" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
            initial-instance="2016-12-01T00:00Z" timezone="IST">
            <uri-template>
                /user/cloudera/inp_logs/${YEAR}_${MONTH}_${DAY}
            </uri-template>
            <done-flag></done-flag>
        </dataset>
        <dataset name="opt_logs" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
            initial-instance="2016-12-01T00:00Z" timezone="IST">
            <uri-template>
                /user/cloudera/opt_logs/${YEAR}_${MONTH}_${DAY}
            </uri-template>
            <done-flag>_trigger</done-flag>
        </dataset>
    </datasets>
    <input-events>
        <data-in name="input" dataset="inp_logs">
            <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
        </data-in>
    </input-events>
    <output-events>
        <data-out name="output" dataset="opt_logs">
            <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
        </data-out>
    </output-events>
    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${app_path}</app-path>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have the same issue. I even set empty . I created manually _SUCCESS file. I dig up. Found in book Apache Oozie: The Workflow Scheduler for Hadoop. But I have no idea, if it is valid.

No, files specified in output-events are not automatically created by Oozie, you need to create those files in your Oozie workflow actions.

The output-events configuration is for giving Oozie information on what files will be created by your Oozie workflow actions, which Oozie would use to cleanup files when rerunning/reprocessing a coordinator.